# Using mouse back/forward buttons in Mathematica's help system

Tags: front-end

I have a generic mouse with back/forward buttons. Those buttons are recognized by the system - I can use `xev` to see that they generate events for buttons number 8 and 9.

I am so used to using them for web browsing, that I sometimes end up pressing them when I'm browsing through Mathematica's help system.

Is there some way to bind those buttons to the back/forward functions in the help system? I looked around in the settings but haven't found anything.

I'm using Mathematica 8.0 in Linux, if this is relevant. Any ideas?

Comment: ...and what mouse are you using?

Comment: A generic one, the buttons work in other applications and generate events properly; I added more details to the question.

Comment: Well, from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/DocumentationCenter.html), the *keyboard* shortcuts are `Alt+Left Arrow` for "Back", and `Alt+Right Arrow` for "Forward", so you might be able to do some mapping...

Comment: This works by default in *Mathematica* 7 for Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to make this solution using [`xbindkeys`](http://hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/) and it works well enough:

```
# Bind button 9 to Alt-Right
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Right' 'keyup Alt_L'"
b:9

# Bind button 8 to Alt-Left
"xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Left' 'keyup Alt_L'"
b:8
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows users can accomplish the binding using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com).

Here is a simple script that maps the `wheel right` and `wheel left` mouse buttons to `Alt+Left` and `Alt+Right` (since I don't have a mouse with forward/backward buttons).

```
WheelLeft::!Left
WheelRight::!Right
```

Also useful for pepole who like using the moouse is [StrokeIt](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/), a free program that allows one to bind mince gestures to keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: For my combination (Win7 64, Mathematica 8.04 and Logitech MX Revolution) the back/forward buttons work for the help system out of the box...

Comment: @YvesKlett Nice to know. I have a Logitech RX1000 (win7 64 mma 8.04) which does not have the extra buttons. But `wheel left` `wheel right` work nicely and I have not been using them until now:)

Comment: With the same mouse, but earlier versions (of Windows and Mathematica and the Logitech drivers) this did not work, so I cannot tell which update triggered this goodie ;-)